# Which Roles are needed in IAM in order to do a firebase deploy

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-iam

I'm trying to add the needed roles for a CI pipeline to automatically deploy to firebase (by running `firebase deploy`.

The roles I've added so far are:

- API Keys viewer
- Artifact registry writer
- Cloud build Service Account
- Cloud Functions Admin
- Cloud Run Viewer
- Firebase App distribution admin
- Firebase Authentication admin
- firebase hosting admin
- firebase rules admin
- service account user
- service usage admin

Honnestly at this point I'm just adding what sounds good, as the error message is not helpful:

> There was an issue deploying your functions. Verify that your project
> has a Google App Engine instance setup at
> https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine and try again. If this
> issue persists, please contact support.

It works when adding the Owner permission, so this is a permission issue.

Comment: I deleted my previous answer as it was incorrect, have you tried adding Firebase Admin and AppEngine admin?

Comment: @GabrielNexT adding firebase admin solves it ! thanks, I'll accept an updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to deploy the entire project, the most applicable role would be **Firebase Admin**.

I use it in portuguese, so the translation in english may be different.

Answer (score 0):

For deploying the hosting app IAM role must be either an Owner or Editor. Sometimes updating the latest version of a Node Package/Firebase tool will resolve the issue as per my experience.

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

It will provide the globally accessible firebase command.
For reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/iam/roles

For any deployments, you need the first Firebase token which is GCP_SA_key for whatever you want to deploy or update.

There are different scenarios let me elaborate with reference

- Cloud Functions Developer IAM role for deploying functions
- Cloud Scheduler Admin IAM role for scheduling your functions
- Service Account User IAM role By default service account using the APP engine for the deployments process required a service account user role.

You need more roles for Updating Firestore to update rules, indexes, and files.

- Firebase Rules Admin role for updating Firestore rules.
- Cloud Datastore Index Admin role for updating firestore Indexes.
- Firebase Hosting Admin role for updating files.
  Further details reference added :[GitHub Integration/deployments roles](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-firebase)

Comment: the question is in for a CI pipeline, not for an user

Comment: Well as per your question Roles are asked, but to automatically run a pipeline for CI Github actions are used to run code, build applications  and deploy application.Kindly update the question

Comment: You are misreading both the question and the comment. You said `For deploying hosting the iam roles are`, what I ask is `what are the roles for deploying (not just hosting).`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Added further citations and details @Community